# Get employees list whose has completed 5,10,15 and so on years of service .i.e multiple of 5 years

Tags: mysql

I want to get employees list whose has completed 5,10,15 and so on years of service i.e multiple of 5 years. I should get the results from one month before. Suppose if 24-03-2022 an employee is going to complete his 5 or 10 or 15 years service then from 24-02-2022 to 24-03-2022. I should display their results, after 24-03-2022 results should not display.
I have prepared a query which is showing results from 24-02-2022 to 24-03-2023.
I want to display from 24-02-2022 to 24-03-2022. Please correct my query.

```sql
SELECT e.emp_id, e.first_name,eji.join_date 
FROM employee as e 
JOIN employee_job_info as eji on e.id = eji.employee_id 
WHERE 
    timestampdiff(YEAR, eji.join_date,DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL '1' MONTH)) % 5 = 0 
    AND floor(datediff('2022-02-24',eji.join_date)/365)!=0
```

Comment: I guess your requirement is this: list the employees whose 5, 10, 15... th anniversary of `join_date` lies in the calendar month after the present calendar month.  Is that correct? Please [edit] your question to clarify your requirement.

Comment: Specify precise MySQL version. *employees list whose has completed 5,10,15 and so on years of service* Build synthetic table (as CTE or subquery) with reasonable values range (100 years is obviously excess, for example) and use it in query source.

Comment: `AND floor(datediff('2022-02-24',eji.join_date)/365)!=0` Do you remember that some years consists of 366 days?

Comment: @O.Jones I want to display results upto 5 years 0 days
For suppose 24-03-2022 I am going to complete  my 5 years anniversary.
I should display my results from 24-02-2022 to 24-03-2022(i.e one month before and  upto 5 years and 0 days).I dont want to display result for the 5 th year.

Comment: @Akina, I am using mysql8 and mostly employees will be under 5,10,15,20,25,30 years only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need in something like this:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE
cte AS (                                                  -- generate a table with values 5,10,...
    SELECT 5 experience
    UNION ALL
    SELECT experience + 5 FROM cte WHERE experience < 50  -- 50 years seems to be enough
)
SELECT e.emp_id, e.first_name,eji.join_date, cte.experience 
FROM employee AS e 
JOIN employee_job_info AS eji ON e.id = eji.employee_id 
CROSS JOIN cte ON eji.join_date BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL cte.experience YEAR
                                    AND CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL cte.experience YEAR + INTERVAL 1 MONTH;
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Akina, perfectly working. getting results exactly